# What is the idea behind the way the signals are used here?

Tags: c, signals, fork, waitpid, sigprocmask

While reading up and learning about signals, I found a program, that uses signals in a specific way. I tried understand it, but I am not sure, how all the parts of the code interact with another.

Below is the above mentioned code and I added comments, where I have difficulties:

```
#include <dirent.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define CP 5

static volatile int curprocs =0; ; 

static void die() {
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}


static void chldhandler() {
    int e = errno;
    // Why do we use waitpid here? What does it do?
    while(waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG) > 0) {
        curprocs--;
    }
    errno = e;
}


void do_work() {
    time_t t;
    srand((unsigned) time(&t));
    sleep(5+ rand() % 4); 
}

int main() {
    struct sigaction sa = {
        .sa_handler = chldhandler,
        .sa_flags = SA_RESTART,
    };

    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    if (sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, NULL) == -1) {
    exit(-1);
    }

    while(1) {
    sigset_t chld, empty;
    sigemptyset(&empty);
    sigemptyset(&chld);
    sigaddset(&chld, SIGCHLD);  

    // What do the following lines of code do??
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &chld, NULL); 
    while (curprocs >= CP) { // cap for the number of child processes 
        sigsuspend(&empty); 
    }
    curprocs++; 
    sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &chld, NULL);

    pid_t p = fork();
    if (p == -1) { 
        return -1;
    }
    if (p == 0) {
        // code for the child processes to execute
        do_work(); 
        die();
    } else {
    // Parent process does nothing 
    }
}
return 0; 
}
```

Obviously above program is intended to have a max amount of 42 child processes doing work. Whenever we want to have a new child process, we use fork, and adjust `curprocs`. 
Whenever a child process finishes, chldhandler() is called and `curprocs` is adjusted as well.

However I don't understand the interplay of the two `sigproc_mask, sigsuspend, waitpid` and our two `signalsets chld, empty`.

Can someone explain what these lines do or why they are used the way they are?

Comment: The comment sign is `//`, not `\\\`. Did you compile this?

Comment: Odds are, it creates a race condition with its use of `curprocs`.  The `++` and `--` operators are not atomic.

Comment: the posted code does not compile!.  Amongst many other problems, it is missing the needed `#include` statements for the needed header files.  When compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  ( for `gcc`, at a minimum use: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11` )  Note: other compilers use different options to produce the same results\

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.  2) separate code blocks: `for` `if` `else` `while` `do...while` `switch` `case` `default` via a single blank line.  3) separate functions by 2 or 3 blank lines (be consistent)

Comment: OT: regarding: `while (curprocs >= 42)`  The posted code contains some 'magic' numbers.  'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 42.  'magic' numbers make the code much more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using a `enum` statement or `#define` statement(s) to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you to debug it.

Answer (score 2):

`sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &chld, NULL);` blocks `SIGCHLD` so that you can be sure that while you do `while (curprocs >= 42)` the `SIGCHLD` handler won't interrupt the code, changing `curprocs` in the middle of the check.

`sigsuspends` atomically unblocks it and waits for a `SIGCHLD` (any signal really, since your passing an empty mask), atomically reblocking it when it returns.

The `waitpid(-1,/*...*/)` in the handler reaps the status of *any* (that's what the -1 means) child that has a status change (typically termination notification) pending so that the data the kernel associates with the status change can be freed. The second argument would be where the status change info would go but since you passed `NULL`, the info will simply be dropped. `WNOHANG` means don't wait if there aren't any more status change notifications.

Since the handler is run in response to `SIGCHLD`, there should be at least one status change notification, but there could be more because `SIGCHLD`s can coalesce (it's also possible there isn't any — if you called `waitpid` from normal context while `SIGCHLD` was blocked). That's why the handler loops. The `WNOHANG` is important because without it, after all the status change notifications have been reaped, the `waitpid` call would block your process until a new notification arrived.